# JavaScript class function this operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS class that contains a AJAX post. I'm trying to refer to the class members from within the post function using `this` but it doesn't seem to be working.

For example, from this:

```
function Classy() {

  this.goal = 0;

  $.post(   
    "class/initial.php",
    function(back) {                
        this.goal = back.goal;  
  }, "json");       

  this.SampleFunction = function() {
    alert(this.goal);   
  }

}

tester = new Classy();
tester.SampleFunction();
```

The alert box outputs a value of `0`, even though this is definitely not what is coming back from the php file. I think the issue is I need something other than `this` to refer to the parent class. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The concept of classes doesn't exist in ECMAScript 1, 2, 3 and 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Classy() {

    this.goal = 0;

     // jQuery.proxy returns a function
    $.post("class/initial.php", $.proxy(function (back) {
        this.goal = back.goal;
    }, this), "json");
      // ^-------- is manually set in your handler

    this.SampleFunction = function () {
        alert(this.goal);
    }
}
```

You can use the [`jQuery.proxy()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method to ensure the proper `this` value.

---

Another possibility is to use the long form [`jQuery.ajax()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method, where you can set the `context:` parameter to give you the desired `this` value.

```
function Classy() {

    this.goal = 0;

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"class/initial.php", 
        dataType: 'json',
        context: this, // <--set the context of the callbacks
        success: function (back) {
            this.goal = back.goal;
        }
    });    
    this.SampleFunction = function () {
        alert(this.goal);
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea isn't bad, but the implementation is out of order (should be `}, this), "json");`, I think.

Comment: @Craig: Thanks. Threw it together a little too quick I guess. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your outrageously fast response. I think I will go with your second method; just as a matter of semantics. At a glance it's fairly apparent what's going on. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`this` means something different inside the anonymous function which jQuery invokes in a callback. So just capture it first:

```
function Classy() {

  this.goal = 0;
  var $t = this;

  $.post(   
    "class/initial.php",
    function(back) {                
        $t.goal = back.goal;  
  }, "json");       

  this.SampleFunction = function() {
    alert(this.goal);   
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works perfectly. I will go with Patrick's solution though, just because it seems to be the "right" way to go about doing this.

Comment: Come on Craig... can we please do this the 'right' way?

Answer (score 0):

In event handlers, `this` refers to the object which fired the event.  An AJAX success callback is really an event handler for the XMLHttpRequest object that does the work, so in this case, `this` refers to the XMLHttpRequest object (well, actually a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object).  To get a reference to your object, assign `this` to a variable that you can reference from within your event handler:

```
function Classy() {
    this.goal = 0;
    var that = this;
    $.post("class/initial.php", function(back) {                
        that.goal = back.goal;  
    }, "json");     
}
```